# Will experience orbs burn in lava in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to get rid of many XP orbs. Once my friend died, he dropped so many orbs that server started lagging terribly. Eventually I absorbed them all. Now, if I die, the server will crash again.

So if I die in lava, will all XP orbs burn away and be destroyed?

Comment: You could make tons of enchanted books too, you know?

Comment: @Mindwin, you could edit original answer, because last time it was edited in 2011.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they burn.

I also had a very nasty experience with the server going down due to XP orb lag and tested the lava bath method in 1.8. It seems to work, I did a 2x2 lava pool and when returning from the dead no XP was left at all.

I'm not sure if they fixed the XP orb lag in 1.9Pre but untill I know for sure I take regular cleansing lava baths.

Comment: Magma is always the solution. Dwarf Fortress has taught me this.